# js alert in add_filter function for image_send_to_editor

Tags: images, filters, javascript

Before inserting an image into 
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'filter_function', 20, 3);
How can I put error msg/alert message instead of returning result into editor?

Thanks

Vivek P

Answer (score 0):

You can try as like this, it may help you.

```
function filter_image_send_to_editor( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt ) { 
    if('your error statement') {
      $html = '<script>alert("Some Error Message")</script>';
    } else {
        //your continue code
    }
    return $html; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'filter_image_send_to_editor', 10, 8 );
```

More Info Regarding image_send_to_editor Filter : http://hookr.io/filters/image_send_to_editor/

Comment: Instead of alerting it is printing message on the editor